# AsyncTypeahead options disappear immediately after search

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

The options return briefly and then immediately disappear. It looks like the component is being automatically re-rendered after the options return.

```
            <AsyncTypeahead
            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
            onSearch={query => {
              this.setState({isLoading: true});
              fetch(`http://localhost/coalmining/app_dev.php/getTypeOfInjuryIncapacity?query=${query}`,{
                  method: "GET",
                })
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(json => this.setState({
                  isLoading: false,
                  options: json.data,
                }))
                ;
            }}
            labelKey={'value'}
            options={this.state.options}
          />
```